# Why isn't always possible to set a winforms dimensions?

Tags: winforms

I'm trying to size a checkboxlist control to 500,250 from its current 502,251 (It's an OCD thing) but every time I try, it just reverts to 502,251.

Is it because the parent container is docked in the window? Are there any workarounds?

(This is through the visual designer)

Comment: If it is docked in its parent container it is presumably resizable, so why does the initial size matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the control is being resized due to the control's font size. The ListControl does not like to display an item that will be "split" by the bottom edge, so it will resize the height. Try changing the control's font size and adjust again to verify.

No work around, and you really do not what one, because the control is really doing the right thing.

Yes, it is OCD. I have it also, but this one you have to let go. :O) Consider yourself lucky because you are only one or two pixels off. I was five pixels off once, and I had to put a note on my monitor to ignore it. It so bothered me.